# ARM Neon: VPADAL for subtraction

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I'm using `VPADAL.U32` instruction to greatly increase my Addition code speed. However, I would need something to subtract with accumulation and carry (exactly what I got as addition).

Wishful thinking or actually possible?

From what I could gather, I'd need to decrement my 2nd operand, then not its bits ... do the `VPADAL`, and then bit-test for a 1, and subtract 1 from the resulting carry (to either get 0 or -1 -- my accumulation).

Am I missing an arcane technique somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use VPADDL to pairwise sum the addends and double the width, then use VQSUB to subtract this term from your total.